# How to send http request with nodejs AWS Lambda?

Tags: node.js, http, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm using AWS Lambda to drive an Alexa Skill Kit development. In an attempt to track events, I'd like the script to send an HTTP request on launch, however from the cloud logs it appears as though the http.get function is being skipped during the execution process.

The code is shown below (google.com replaces the analytics tracking url - which has been tested in the browser);

```js
exports.handler = function (event, context) {

    var skill = new WiseGuySkill();
    var http = require('http');

    var url = 'http://www.google.com';
    console.log('start request to ' + url)
    http.get(url, function(res) {
        console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
        // context.succeed();
    }).on('error', function(e) {
        console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
        // context.done(null, 'FAILURE');
    });
    console.log('end request to ' + url);

    skill.execute(event, context);
};
```

The context objects have been commented out to allow for 'skill.execute' to function, yet either way this HTTP request is not executing. Only the 'start' and 'end' console.logs are recorded, those internal in the function do not.

Is this a async issue? Thanks.

Comment: I just copied and pasted your http request code and I got `start request to http://www.google.com`, `end request to http://www.google.com`, and `Got response: 200` in my console. Are you sure this `handler` function is being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to successfully complete the http request, the http.get function must be incorporated into a callback function. Else the process will not be completed and will end prematurely, using a callback allows the http request to complete (with or without an error) before continuing with the rest of the function.

```
WiseGuySkill.prototype.eventHandlers.onLaunch = function (launchRequest, session, response) {

    // Call requestFunction to make the http.get call.
    // Get response from requestFunction using requestCallback
    requestFunction(function requestCallback(err) {

        // If error occurs during http.get request - respond with console.log
        if (err) {
            console.log('HTTP Error: request not sent');
        }

        ContinueIntent(session,response);
    });
};
```

The function 'requestFunction' calls http.get and fires the callback.

```
function requestFunction(requestCallback){

        var url = "http://www.google.com";

        http.get(url, function(res) {
            console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
            requestCallback(null);
        }).on('error', function (e) {
            console.log("Got error: ", e);
        });
    }
```

And obviously ensure you have required 'http' at the start of the script.
Hope this helps anybody else new to this!

Comment: I am curious though- why do you need to wrap your request within another function with another callback? The function you pass in to the `http.get` request is already a callback.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the handler is being triggered. There are two ways of accomplishing this:

- You could set up a new API endpoint and execute a request on that.
- You could hit the Test button and your function would be invoked with the given data.

I copied and pasted your whole snippet except for the first and the last lines (because I don't have `customSkill` defined anywhere). I was able to get a `200` response code.

Comment: Thanks for the response, this works for me as well.

However the customSkill is actually the 'wiseGuy' Alexa Skill Kit sample amazon provides (found here https://github.com/amzn/alexa-skills-kit-js/tree/master/wiseGuy ) (I've edited the question to make this clearer).

When executing wiseguy in the exports handler - it's as if the http.get response is blocked and is never sent. What might be causing that, in the wiseguy code?

Comment: @user2075625 Interesting.. Have you registered the skill in the developer portal? Also, what region is your server located? From Amazon's developer page: `Lambda functions for Alexa skills must be hosted in the US East (N. Virginia) region. Currently, this is the only Lambda region the Alexa Skills Kit supports.`

Comment: Thanks for your help on this, turns out I required a callback within the the http.get request to ensure the request was fully actualised. I showed the working in my answer.

Thanks for your time though!

Comment: @user2075625 No problem, and be sure to mark yours as the answer if it worked for you.