# How to call a POST API from lambda function?

Tags: post, aws-lambda

I am trying to integrate a POST API call from a lambda function using Node.js 12.x.

I tried like below:

```
var posturl = "My post api path";
var jsonData = "{'password':'abcdef','domain':'www.mydomain.com','username':'abc.def'}";
var req = require('request');
const params = {
    url: posturl,
    headers: { 'jsonData': jsonData }
};
req.post(params, function(err, res, body) {
    if(err){
        console.log('------error------', err);
    } else{
        console.log('------success--------', body);
    }
});
```

But when I am execute it using state machine, I am getting the below exception:

```
{
  "errorType": "Error",
  "errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'request'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js",
  "trace": [
    "Error: Cannot find module 'request'",
    "Require stack:",
    "- /var/task/index.js",
    "- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js",
    "- /var/runtime/index.js",
    "    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)",
    "    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)",
    "    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)",
    "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:8:14)",
    "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
  ]
}
```

Here the posturl is my api path and jsondata is my key value pair data.

So How can I call a POST API from lambda function? How can I pass the entire jsondata key when call API? How can I parse the response after the service call?

**Update: I have tried like below**

All my details are passing with a key jsonData, where I can specify that? Without that key, it will not work.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const http = require('http');
    const data = JSON.stringify({
    password: 'mypassword',
    domain: 'www.mydomain.com',
    username: 'myusername'
});

const options = {
    hostname: 'http://abc.mydomain.com',
    path: 'remaining path with ticket',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': data.length
    }
};

const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
    let data = '';

    console.log('Status Code:', res.statusCode);

    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', () => {
        console.log('Body: ', JSON.parse(data));
    });

}).on("error", (err) => {
    console.log("Error: ", err.message);
});

req.write(data);
req.end();  
};
```

Comment: check out this answer [AWS Lambda HTTP POST Request (Node.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57293327/2246345)

Answer (score 0):

source : [How to Make an HTTP Post Request using Node.js](https://attacomsian.com/blog/node-http-post-request)

```js
const https = require('https');

const data = JSON.stringify({
    name: 'John Doe',
    job: 'Content Writer'
});

const options = {
    hostname: 'reqres.in',
    path: '/api/users',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': data.length
    }
};


const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
    let data = '';

    console.log('Status Code:', res.statusCode);

    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', () => {
        console.log('Body: ', JSON.parse(data));
    });

}).on("error", (err) => {
    console.log("Error: ", err.message);
});

req.write(data);
req.end();
```

Comment: @MatthewPans you are making an `http` request and `importing  https`. For sharing code samples you can use [gists](https://gist.github.com/). `Keep your project related details private.`

Comment: I have added my post api path on `hostname`and `path` sections. And added the username, password and domain name under the data section. But all these datas are collectively added as a json data with key `jsonData`. Where we can add that key? Could you please elaborate the answer with these points. Please don't post private url and data, just put some dummy data instead of that.

Comment: @MatthewPans the url and ticket details I saw. If they are not something you wanna protect, that's fine.

Comment: @MatthewPans try this [gist](https://gist.github.com/toddlers/c89958d9a3db93a75c42c9a6a678dfc2)

Comment: I have edited the question with how I have tried, could you please check the update1 section of question.

Comment: Hello, any update? I am still not able to call the post api from lambda function.

Comment: @MatthewPans I am not able to test the solution yet.

Comment: I need to know about only one thing, where we are passing the body?